# Cabal: Blocking base packages from installing

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, cabal-install

I'm using cabal-install 1.14.0 on Ubuntu 12.04, and ghc 7.4.1.

Some cabal packages I try to install are pulling in [`directory-1.2.0.0`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.2.0.0), which requires ghc 7.6. Is there a way to configure cabal to not even attempt to install directory-1.2.0.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a constraint,

```
cabal install foo --constraint="directory < 1.2"
```

or, as [Daniel Wagner reminded me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809903/cabal-blocking-base-packages-from-installing/12809940#comment17325121_12809940), better, since it really prevents reinstalls,

```
cabal install foo --constraint="directory installed"
```

and if you want that globally, add that to your cabal config file (~/.cabal/config on Linux and Mac, Somewhere in \Users\You\AppData on Windows, iirc), that has a line

```
-- constraint:
```

uncomment that and add the constraint.

Comment: Exactly the same place on Mac as Linux.

Comment: Even better is the "directory installed" constraint, which prevents reinstalls (even of the exact same version but rebuilt against differently versioned dependencies).

Comment: Excellent, @DanielWagner. Completely forgot about that.

Comment: Where it is under MS Windows depends on what version you're using and whether you're on a LAN etc. You can find out reliably in a Command Prompt window by typing `cd %appdata%`

Comment: You can also find it by typing `%appdata%` in windows explorer